# How to automatically Open Exported Excel File

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel

So I have this code that Export string I pass to excel

```
        Response.Clear()
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=MyExcelData.xls")
        Response.Charset = ""
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        Response.Output.Write(myDataString)
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()
```

This code ask me to open or save the file. My question is is there a way that automatically open the file without asking me to either open or save the file???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is the browser/user to determine what to to. You can try to change the content type to display the "Open / Save" browser popup.

Comment: Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
What should it be?

Comment: Try 'application/octet-stream'